# How can I open an Image file using fs in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

In my current codes, it does only can read a text file, How can I make an Image (base64) file opened with Photos Application (Windows)? Is there any chance to do that? If it's impossible, please let me know!

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('./Test/a.txt', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }
    console.log(data)
    return
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution is like this:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

const imageFilePath = '/aaa/bbb/ccc'

const c = cp.spawn('a_program_that_opens_images', [ `"${imageFilePath}"` ]);  


c.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);  
c.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);


c.once('exit', exitCode => { 

   // child process has exited

});
```

Comment: It doesn't work well on mine, It gives me an output something like this: `throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event, errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn program_that_opens_images', path: 'program_that_opens_images', spawnargs: [ 'C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/MYFolder/Test/MyPic.png' ]`

Comment: Because "program_that_opens_images" is not a real program - put the right path to the program there

Comment: Figure it out? Happy to provide more input

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const c = cp.spawn('bash');  // 1

const imageFilePath = '/aaa/bbb/ccc'

c.stdin.end(` 
   program_that_opens_images "${imageFilePath}"
`);  // 2

c.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);  // 3
c.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

c.once('exit', exitCode => {    // 4
   // child process has exited

});
```

what it does:

1. spawns a bash child process (use `sh` or `zsh` instead if you want)
2. writes to bash stdin, (inputting the command to run)
3. pipes the stdio from the child to the parent
4. captures the exit code from the child

Comment: note on windows, you may wish to use my other answer